# Scrapinghub/Splash - Aquarium is not working on docker-compose

Tags: docker, docker-compose, scrapinghub, splash-js-render

We are trying to use Aquarium, to set up the Scrapinghub/Splash. While installation, when I use "docker-compose up" to start the Splash, It throws the exception

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "/usr/local/bin/docker-compose", line 11, in 
>       sys.exit(main())
>     File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/compose/cli/main.py", line 71, in main
>       command()
>     File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/compose/cli/main.py", line 124, in perform_command
>       project = project_from_options('.', options)
>     File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/compose/cli/command.py", line 41, in project_from_options
>       compatibility=options.get('--compatibility'),
>     File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/compose/cli/command.py", line 121, in get_project
>       host=host, environment=environment
>     File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/compose/cli/command.py", line 92, in get_client
>       environment=environment, tls_version=get_tls_version(environment)
>     File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/compose/cli/docker_client.py", line 127, in docker_client
>       client = APIClient(**kwargs)
>     File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/docker/api/client.py", line 113, in **init**
>       config_dict=self._general_configs
>   TypeError: load_config() got an unexpected keyword argument 'config_dict'

Currently, I am using,
Docker version 18.06.0-ce,
docker-compose version 1.22.0.

Please help me to solve this issue.

Comment: I refer this URL to install https://github.com/TeamHG-Memex/aquarium

Comment: please share the `docker-compose.yml` file

Comment: I fixed this issue by reinstalling my docker and docker-compose.

Comment: I think this issue might occur due to the patentability issue.